# iOS 5.0 detect when the App is re-activated from a URL in Safari.app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In our workflow the user:

1. Starts a transaction in the App
2. Is redirected to Safari.app to confirm the transaction
3. Is redirected back to the app via link: `myapp://finish-transaction` where the transaction is checked again
4. The UI is updated based on the result

While my app get's re-activated when I click the link in Safari, I found it weird that none of these methods get called, upon reactivation.

- `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`
- `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive:`
- `applicationWillEnterForeground:`
- `viewDidAppear:` or `viewWillAppear:` in the current `UIViewController`
- `application:handleOpenURL:`

I have the urlscheme `myapp` registered as an editor for the identifier `com.mycompany.myapp` in the `Info.plist`.

So how do I find out if the App was re-activated under iOS 5.0?

Comment: Just a guess but did you added URL schemes in plist file ?

Comment: @Jennis Yes I have, the app is re-activated when I touch the link, I just don't get notified. I'll update my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
     // Handle open here   
}
```

Comment: I tried this too (will add it to the list). Please note that it is deprecated in iOS 5

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. Learn something new everyday. Cheers!

Comment: I use [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash/) for looking all sorts of API documentation. It's quite handy and told me that it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

So now this is embarrassing. I had multiple versions of the App installed in the simulator. So when coming back from the Webpage the wrong App would launch... And I would wait in vain for some love from the App which was still inactive...